# Styles for paragraphs

Tags: css

I use a content management system, so do not have access to style sheets.  However the "Easy Editor" is pretty useless, and creates a lot of code.  Basically, If I have 3 paragraphs which should all be formatted the same, i.e. color, font-size, font-family and text align, I can only get it to apply to all 3 paragraphs by inserting a p style with all the formatting before each paragraph and then at the end of each paragraph, close the p tag.  Then repeat for each paragraph.  I have tried just applying one span and also one div at the top of the three paragraphs and then closing it at the end of the third paragraph but it goes wrong.  Is there anyway that I can declare what the format is for all three paragraphs just the once?

Would appreciate any help you can give

Comment: can you please show some code

Comment: Unless `style` element is allowed, you would need to get a plugin that applies CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use an internal `css`

```
<style type="text">
p{
  color:
  font-size:
  font-family:
  text align:
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant access the stylesheet simply insert the styles directly on the page within a style tag.

```html
<style>
  .para{
    color:#b00;
    font-size:20px;
}
</style>
<p>Paragrah 1</p>
<p>Paragrah 2</p>
<p class="para">Paragrah 3</p>
<p>Paragrah 4</p>
<p class="para">Paragrah 5</p>
<p>Paragrah 6</p>
<p class="para">Paragrah 7</p>
<p>Paragrah 8</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have access to CSS you can do it directly on p tag

```html
<p class="style:font-familmy:arial;color:#000,font-size:16px"> </p>
```

Its not best solution but for small and fast fix it will be OK